# Form created from a form - can't reach from other forms

Tags: c#

I create a form in the main form. It is a small "widget" on the screen (always visible, always on top). When the main form is active I can reach the widget without any problem (eg. change position on the screen with mouse).

But when I open other forms then I can not reach the widget ("ding" sound).

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you opening the other forms using ShowDialog? That would make it modal and prevent your clicking of other windows

Comment: Use `Show` instead of `ShowModal` More here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yes, I am using ShowDialog for other forms because I do not want to click back to main form when other form is active. But you are right, it prevents to click to the widget.